# qt- displaying form in tab widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

Me and my friend have made two separate forms in qt but we want to display both the form in tab widget i.e. one form in one tab page and another form in another tab page . how can i do that?

previously,we used buttons to toggle between the forms but it seem to be in convenient so we want to change it.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
```

`#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
 #include "ui_partspro.h"`

`MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)`
`{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new Ui::partspro,"test");
}`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a QTabWidget and assign your forms to separate pages of the tab widget.

Comment: how do i assign a form to tab?

Comment: QTabWidget::addTab. You'll need to read the documentation on it.

Comment: addTab allows to add widget not a form

Comment: A "form" is a widget. Unless you're talking about QML, but you haven't actually said.

Comment: i am not talking about QML. i am confused .can you help with code?i will appreciate :]

Comment: If you can post the code you've used to create the "forms", then I probably help better. Without it, all I can say is that Qt doesn't have a "form" as an object type. It has QWidget and subclasses of QWidget. When you use Qt Designer or Creator to create a "form", you are drawing on a QWidget or subclass of it. To put a "form" on a tab, it's a QWidget, so the method I mentioned above works.

Comment: i have to add partspro.ui in the tabwidget created in mainwindow.ui . see above code

Comment: Assuming "Ui::partspro" is your form, which is a widget as I've said, that code looks correct.